# GCP Loading a Data as String into BigQuery table from a CSV file in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

A CSV file in Google Cloud Storage has a date value in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, which when loaded into a Bigquery table, it goes as 'mm/dd/yyyy' format.

To counter it, I created a table with the said field as 'string' and when trying to load the data from the file it says:

```
Provided Schema does not match Table <table name>. Field TRADE_DATE has changed type from STRING to DATE
```

How do I load Date as String from a CSV file into a BigQuery table?

Answer (score 0):

Since you created table beforehand and ~date values quotated, BQ shouldn't behave like this.

is there any chance to your `Load Job` has `--autodetect` configuration still?

Comment: I'm loading the data from the SQL workspace with the Schema Autodetect checked. The date value itself in the file is not quoted. Will this be an issue?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if quotations needed now. But first; give it a try without `Autodetect`. Since the table already created, you don't need to infer the schema. @S.Nori

Comment: If I deselect Autodetect, it fails with this error message: It looks like you are appending to an existing table with autodetect enabled. Disabling autodetect may resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table already has a schema with the date column defined as string data type, when you are trying to load the data from GCS with auto-detect on, there is a schema mis-match. The auto-detect schema reads the date column as date data type rather than string. If you are unchecking the auto-detect schema option, you need to provide the schema manually while loading the data.

Consider using the following steps:-

- Create a table from the CSV file in the GCS bucket and manually provide the schema by keeping the auto-detect schema option unchecked.
- Provide data type as string for the date column. Skip the header row, if any, using advanced options drop-down.
- Parse the date column say ‘TDate’ to the correct format running the following query on the table:-

```
SELECT Tid, parse_date("%d/%m/%Y", TDate) as TDate FROM `projectName.DatasetName.tableName`
```

- I have used ‘/’ as a separator in the format string to match the date format provided by you. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date) for more supported format elements.
- Save the result of the above query in a different table by clicking the ‘Save Results’ button on the console. You can see the datatype of the ‘TDate’ column is date in the new table. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results) if you need help with saving the query output to a table.
- You can verify if BigQuery is recognising the date in the format you have parsed by running the following query:-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(Day FROM TDate ) as Day, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TDate ) as Month FROM `projectName.DatasetName.tableName`
```

- You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract) for more information on date functions in BigQuery.

If changing the CSV file is an option for you then you can refer to this [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations). It mentions that while you load data from a CSV file to BigQuery, values in the ‘Date’ column must use the ‘-’ separator and the date must be in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.